# Cannot export Interface in OSGI

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, spring

I am trying to export an interface (ITestRunable) I am sure I have linked everything correctly in the context.xml and osgi.xml files but it just wont work. The error is:

Application context initialization for 'me.overlaymanagement' has timed out waiting for (objectClass=me.overlaymanagement.testing.ITestRunable)

Any got any idea?

Code: Spring files for ITestRunable

context.xml

```
  <bean id="testingRunable"   class="me.overlaymanagement.testing.Testing"
init-method="startUp" destroy-method="shutDown">
  </bean>
```

osgi.xml

```
<osgi:service id="testingRunable" ref="testingRunable">
    <osgi:interfaces>
      <value>me.overlaymanagement.testing.ITestRunable</value>
    </osgi:interfaces>
 </osgi:service>
```

Spring files for import into main system

context.xml

```
<bean id="overlaymanagementsystem" 
    class="me.overlaymanagementsystem.OverlayManagementSystem"
    init-method="startUp" destroy-method="shutDown">
    <property name="testingRunable" ref="testingRunable"/>
 </bean>
```

osgi.xml

```
<osgi:reference id="testingRunable" cardinality="1..1"
  interface="me.overlaymanagement.testing.ITestRunable">      
</osgi:reference>
```

Gettors and Settors for ITestRunable within main system

```
public class OverlayManagementSystem{
     ...
    protected ITestRunable testingRunable;
    ....
    public ITestRunable getTestRunable() {
    return testingRunable;
    }   

    public void setTestRunable(ITestRunable testingRunable) {
    this.testingRunable = testingRunable;
    }
 }
```

can anyone see a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i managed to find the poblem. It was two things actually:

1. It didnt like that i had set the bean id and the service id where the ITestRunable code is located. Once i changed the service id name to something different it gave me a new error about invalid gettors and settors, which is the next point.
2. after some research i found the your gettor and setter for the imported service must be that same as the beans property name for that service. notice in my bean its:

   < property name="testingRunable" .../>

and the get/set are defined as: "getTestRunable/setTestRunable". Changing these to getTestingRunable and setTestingRunable solved the problem for me.

I hope this helps others.